# solving a nonlinear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, stability-in-odes

a friend of mine asked a question before, which seemed easy at first glance, but it has occupied my mind afterward. Here is the question:
\begin{equation}
\dot{X_1}=\dot{U_1}U_2-\dot{f}(t)\\
\dot{X_2}=\dot{U_1}X_1-\dot{g}(t)
\end{equation}
Where $\dot{f}$ and $\dot{g}$ are bounded known derivatives with zeros as the initial values. Find bounded signals $U_1$ and $U_2$, so that $X_1$ and $X_2$ stabilize (converge to a bounded set or became a bounded function). I have suggested the answer below, for $\dot{X_1}$ equation, but I can't extend it to a general solution:
\begin{equation}
U_1 = -\cos(f)\\
U_2 = \sin(f)
\end{equation}
By applying them to the $\dot{X_1}$ equation, we get:
\begin{align}
\dot{X_1}&=\dot{f}\sin(f)\sin(f)-\dot{f}\\
&=-\dot{f}cos(2f)+\dot{f}-\dot{f}\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\dot{\sin}(2f)\\
\to X_1&=-\frac{1}{2}\sin(2f)
\end{align}
Thanks in advance, and any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a solution in the form you are looking for, but if you allow feedback ($U_1,U_2$ depend on $X_1,X_2$), then $\dot{U_1},U_2$ can be designed as controllers to enforce boundedness of $X_1,X_2$. We have two controllers $\dot{U_1},U_2$ and two outputs $X_1,X_2$. However, when $X_1(t)=0$, we loose controlability of $X_2(t)$ since $\dot{X_2} = -\dot{g}$ in this case no matter what we assign to $\dot{U_1},U_2$. Thus, in addition to the goal of enforcing $X_1,X_2$ to be bounded, it is required to make $|X_1(t)|$ bounded from bellow at least after some time in order to ensure controlability. Under this setting, a possible controller design is the following: first, we cancel the term $-\dot{f}$ to make $X_1$ converge to a desired bounded interval far from the origin, e.g. of the form $|X_1(t)|\in[\beta/2,\beta]$ for all $t\geq t^*$ after some time $t^*>0$ and some $\beta>0$. Then, we design a controller for $X_2$ provided that $X_1$ reaches such interval.

The concrete controller is described in the following:

**Controller**:

Let $X_1(0)$ be the initial condition for $X_1(t)$. Additionally, choose any $\beta,\delta>0$ and any $\varepsilon>\max\left(|\dot{g}|,\frac{|\dot{g}|(1+\bar{\sigma})}{\underline{\sigma}}\right)$ with $\underline{\sigma} := \frac{|X_1(0)|+\beta/2}{|X_1(0)|+\beta + \delta}>0$ and $\bar{\sigma}:=\frac{|X_1(0)|+\beta}{|X_1(0)|+\beta/2 + \delta}>0$. Moreover, define $\text{sign}(x)=1$ if $x\geq 0$ and $\text{sign}(x)=-1$ otherwise. Hence, the control feedback is:

$$
\dot{U}_1(t) = \frac{\dot{g}(t)-\varepsilon\text{sign}(X_2(t))}{(|X_1(t)|+\delta)\text{sign}(X_1(t))}
$$

$$
{U}_2(t) = \frac{[\dot{f}(t)-X_1(t)+X_1(0)+\beta\text{sign}(X_1(0))](|X_1(t)|+\delta)\text{sign}(X_1(t))}{\dot{g}(t)-\varepsilon\text{sign}(X_2(t))}
$$

**Proof of correctness**:

To check that this works, first lets analyze $\dot{X}_1$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\dot{X}_1 &=
 \dot{U}_1U_2 - \dot{f} \\&= \left(\frac{\dot{g}-\varepsilon\text{sign}(X_2)}{(|X_1|+\delta)\text{sign}(X_1)}\right)\left(\frac{[\dot{f}-X_1+X_1(0)+\beta\text{sign}(X_1(0))](|X_1|+\delta)\text{sign}(X_1)}{\dot{g}-\varepsilon\text{sign}(X_2)}\right) - \dot{f}\\ &= -X_1+X_1(0)+\beta\text{sign}(X_1(0))
\end{aligned}
$$
Note that $X_1(t) = \text{sign}(X_1(0))(|X_1(0)|+\beta(1-e^{-t}))$ is the unique solution to  $\dot{X}_1(t) = -X_1(t)+X_1(0)+\beta\text{sign}(X_1(0))$. Moreover, since we defined $\text{sign}(0) = 1$, thus, $|X_1(t)|$ is bounded from above by $|X_1(0)| + \beta$ and is bounded from bellow for any $t>0$ even when $X_1(0)=0$. Thus, dividing by $|X_1|+\delta$ in the expression for $\dot{U}_1$ is not problematic (no singularity) and $\dot{U}_1(t)$ will remain bounded.

Now, lets analyze $\dot{X}_2$. First, note that there are no $t\geq 0$ such that $\dot{g}(t)-\varepsilon\text{sign}(X_2(t))= 0$. Otherwise, there would exist $t\geq 0$ such that
$
\dot{g}(t) =  \varepsilon\text{sign}(X_2(t))
$
which implies $|\dot{g}(t)| = \varepsilon$ for some $t$, which is not possible since $\varepsilon>|\dot{g}|$. Hence, dividing by $\dot{g}-\varepsilon\text{sign}(X_2)$ is not problematic in the expression for $U_2$ (no singularity).
Now, to obtain boundedness of $X_2$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\dot{X}_2 &= \dot{U_1}X_1-\dot{g} \\&= \left(\frac{\dot{g}-\varepsilon\text{sign}(X_2)}{(|X_1|+\delta)\text{sign}(X_1)}\right)X_1 - \dot{g} \\&= -\varepsilon\text{sign}(X_2)\sigma(X_1) + \left(\sigma(X_1)-1\right)\dot{g}
\end{aligned}
$$
where we defined $$\sigma(X_1):=\frac{X_1}{(|X_1|+\delta)\text{sign}(X_1)} = \frac{|X_1|\text{sign}(X_1)}{(|X_1|+\delta)\text{sign}(X_1)}=\frac{|X_1|}{|X_1|+\delta}$$
and used the fact that $X_1=|X_1|\text{sign}(X_1)$.

Moreover, note that $|X_1(t)|$ basically goes from $|X_1(0)|$ towards $|X_1(0)| + \beta$ asymptotically and without touching zero (except perhaps at $t=0$). Hence, there exist some $t^*$ at which $|X_1(t^*)|\geq |X_1(0)|+\beta/2$. Hence, we can bound $\sigma(X_1)$ from bellow by:
$$
\frac{|X_1(t)|}{|X_1(t)|+\delta}\geq \frac{|X_1(0)|+\beta/2}{|X_1(0)|+\beta + \delta}=\underline{\sigma}
$$
for $t\geq t^*$. Similarly, we obtain
$$
\frac{|X_1(t)|}{|X_1(t)|+\delta}\leq\frac{|X_1(0)|+\beta}{|X_1(0)|+\beta/2 + \delta}=\bar{\sigma}
$$

We check the boundedness of $X_2$ by a Lyapunov function argument for $t\geq t^*$ and verify boundedness for $0\leq t\leq t^*$ in a later step. Let $V = X_2^2/2$ and compute $\dot{V}$ for $t\geq t^*$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\dot{V} &= X_2\dot{X}_2 \\&= X_2(-\varepsilon\text{sign}(X_2)\sigma(X_1) + \left(\sigma(X_1)-1\right)\dot{g}) \\&=  -\sigma(X_1)\varepsilon |X_2| + (\sigma(X_1)-1)\dot{g}X_2\\&\leq  - \underline{\sigma}\varepsilon |X_2| + |{\sigma(X_1)}-1||\dot{g}||X_2| \\
&\leq  - \underline{\sigma}\varepsilon |X_2| +({\bar{\sigma}}+1)|\dot{g}||X_2| \\
&=  -|X_2|(\underline{\sigma}\varepsilon- (\bar{\sigma}+1)|\dot{g}|)<0
\end{aligned} 
$$
since $\varepsilon>|\dot{g}|(1+\bar{\sigma})/\underline{\sigma}$.
Therefore, $V=X_2^2/2$ always decreases, and thus stability (and boundedness) for $X_2$ follows for $t\geq t^*$.

Now, since the controller $\dot{U_1}$ and $X_1,\dot{g}$ remain bounded, then $X_2$ will remain bounded for $0\leq t \leq t^*$ (no escapes in finite time before $t=t^*$). Thus we have showed that the controllers have no singularities (thus are bounded) and they effectively make $X_1,X_2$ remain bounded.

Comment: The might be a couple of typos here but hopefully you can get the idea.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that's great, and I've learned a lot, but according to the question, $U_1$ needs to be bounded and not $\dot{U_1}$, is there a way to work it around? By the way, I like the ideas you used in this solution very much.

Comment: Well, making $U_1$ bounded is more complicated. Are you sure there is a solution? I mean, the problem is that if you want to mantain $X_1$ bounded from bellow (in order to not to loose controlpability or $X_2$) we have to be persistently exciting $X_1$, so $\dot{U}_1$ may not be able to vanish (making $U_1$ approximatelly constant after some time). If there were no disturbances $f,g$ I guess it would be possible. I mean, I'm not saying its not possible, but I think it is more complicated. I will think about it later.

Comment: Also, $U_1$ remain bounded for any finite time horizon. Anyway, at least you learned something from my answer. Thats nice to know!